How can vcpkg-installed-lib and single-down-load lib use together in CLion
Case 1.
I usually install cxx libs with vcpkg.
I use Clion to build and run my project. My CLion version is 2024.1.1
I set -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/my/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake on CLion-settings.
The setting path is: Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - CMake - CMake options, as the screenshot shows:
enter image description here
Case 2
Sometimes I also download the source code and compile it without vcpkg.
I use the boost_1_85_0 recently.
I compiled and install the version boost in a specific path.
If I set the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE as Case 1 does, CLion can not find the boost package.
So I delete the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE setting on CLion.
And add the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH setting in CMakeLists.txt as followed:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(PROJECT_NAME vcpkg_and_singlelib)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

set(BOOST_ROOT "Path/to/boost/installed/boost_1_85_0_install_default")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH        "${BOOST_ROOT}")
find_package(Boost 1.85.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread date_time log log_setup program_options)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Boost::system Boost::thread Boost::date_time Boost::log Boost::log_setup Boost::program_options)

find_package(RapidJSON CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE rapidjson)


But the CLion can not find the packages installed by vcpkg like rapidjson as above showed.
Question:
How can I find packages from both vcpkg and self-installed directory?
I set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE before vcpkg-installed packages and after self-installed packages.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(PROJECT_NAME vcpkg_and_singlelib)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

set(BOOST_ROOT "Path/to/boost/installed/boost_1_85_0")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH        "${BOOST_ROOT}")
find_package(Boost 1.85.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread date_time log log_setup program_options)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Boost::system Boost::thread Boost::date_time Boost::log Boost::log_setup Boost::program_options)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/path/to/my/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

find_package(RapidJSON CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE rapidjson)

But the vcpkg-installed packages still can not be found.
to reply:
I set the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE on clion, and append BOOST_ROOT to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.
Now the CLion can not find the boost of right version.
The CMake on Clion shows:
CMake Error at C:/Path_to_User_Home/program/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost: Found unsuitable version "1.84.0", but required is at
  least "1.85.0" (found
  C:/Path_to_User_Home/program/vcpkg-2024.04.26/installed/x64-windows/include,
  found components: system thread date_time log log_setup program_options
  chrono atomic filesystem regex)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Path_to_User_Home/program/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:592 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Path_to_User_Home/program/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/Path_to_User_Home/program/vcpkg-2024.04.26/installed/x64-windows/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
  C:/Path_to_User_Home/program/vcpkg-2024.04.26/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:813 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Path_to_User_Home/CLionProjects/vcpkg_and_singlelib/cmake-build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Path_to_User_Home/CLionProjects/vcpkg_and_singlelib/cmake-build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Failed to reload]


"I set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE before vcpkg-installed packages and after self-installed packages." - This is useless. The toolchain specified in that variable is included at the first project() call. Setting this variable after the call changes nothing.

Variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is treated by CMake as a list, so it can accommodate several paths. Your code overwrites the variable, so any content added by vcpkg is lost. Instead, append new paths to it:
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${BOOST_ROOT}")


I have tried this method, but it does not work.
The boost installed by myself still can not be found.
And I print the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH with "message(${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})", it shows:
/Path_to_vcpkg/vcpkg-2024.04.26/installed/x64-windows/Path_to_vcpkg/vcpkg-2024.04.26/installed/x64-windows/debug/Path_to_boost/boost_1_85_0_install_default

Please, add to the question post the complete error message about not finding Boost. It looks like the problem is somewhere else.

I set the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE on clion, and append BOOST_ROOT to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.
Now the CLion can not find the boost of right version.
The CMake on Clion shows:
as above I added.

"Now the CLion can not find the boost of right version." - This is important part of the problem. In other words, CMake finds Boost installation, but its version is not suited for the find_package request. Module mode of find_package has no ability to skip improper package and search further. You need to force CMake to search your custom directory first. E.g. you could use PREPEND option instead of APPEND.

It does not work, ether. I even set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, but it still does not work.
list(PREPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${BOOST_ROOT}")
list(PREPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${BOOST_ROOT}")
